# Flutter - Group date wise and show under a sticky header

Tags: list, sqlite, flutter, date, dart

**I want to group all list tiles according dates which are same and show them under sticky bar as shown in the picture. I get the dates from sqlite database.**

The data from the database is in format like this: 21-01-2020.

It should show Today, tomorrow and date for example 28 Nov 2020 as in the picture.

```
ListView.builder(
...
  return listTile(
    title: Text(items[position0].dates), //dates from database, returns 21-01-2020
  ),
),
```

At last I just want results like the below picture by comparing dates from database...The sticky header should be dynamic and change according to database as which one showing today may be yesterday tomorrow.

**[I want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZTxn.jpg)**

Comment: its not the ListTile you need to sort, arrange/sort the data from db according to same date, use the `.where()` method on the list of DateTime you have

Comment: Sorry...but I couldn't get it...I am new to flutter...could you help me out better with some examples